# Using a Enum with a ActionParam

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using the following piece of code in my JSF 2.0 with RichFaces 4.0. I have a managed bean that has an enum. Now i want to assign the value of the enum via an ActionParam. How can I do this? Here is the code:

```
<a4j:commandLink id="pendingTransactions"
        action="#{tellerBean.getPendingTransactions}" value="Show Pending"
        styleClass="button category-btn">
    <a4j:actionparam name="first" value=""
        assignTo="" />  
</a4j:commandLink>
```

and my managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TellerBean implements Serializable{

    public enum TransactionType {
        PENDING,PROCESSED,ALL
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -321111;
    private String recipientID;
    private String recipientName;
    private String transactionAmount;
    private TransactionType transactionType;


    public String getRecipientID() {
        return recipientID;
    }

    public void setRecipientID(String recipientID) {
        this.recipientID = recipientID;
    }

    public String getRecipientName() {
        return recipientName;
    }

    public void setRecipientName(String recipientName) {
        this.recipientName = recipientName;
    }

    public String getTransactionAmount() {
        return transactionAmount;
    }

    public void setTransactionAmount(String transactionAmount) {
        this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
    }

    public void searchTransactions() {}

    public TransactionType getTransactionType() {
        return transactionType;
    }

    public void setTransactionType(TransactionType transactionType) {
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
    }

    public void getTransactions() {}
}
```

Now I want to assign the value of the `transactionType` variable to an Enum value. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do with the variable or how you want to display it, so here's a generic example.

First of all, the JSF page must be able to 'iterate' over the enum to discover the possible values. I'm using `h:selectOneMenu` as an example which is filled using `f:selectItems`. `f:selectItems` expects a `List<>` as input so we need to create a method in the `TellerBean`:

```
public List<TransactionType> getTransactionTypes()
{
    List<TransactionTypes> tt = new ArrayList<TransactionType>();
    for (TransactionType t : TransactionType.values())
    {
        tt.add(new TransactionType(t, t.toString()))
    }
    return tt;
}
```

Then for an example JSF page:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{tellerBean.transactionType}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{tellerBean.transactionTypes}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{tellerBean.someMethod}"/>
</h:form>
```

The JSF page should display a drop-down list with the values of the enum. When clicking the button labeled "Submit" it executes `someMethod()` in `TellerBean`. Of course this doesn't work because the method doesn't exist, but it's just an example. ;-)