# a4j:commandLink not setting value the first time

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have placed three command links in my page. The first time I press one of the command links, its value is not updated in the bean. However, from the second time onwards it works. Can anyone please help me? Is there something to do with having two forms in my JSF?

Here is the code I have been using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>My Registration Page</title>
    <link href="stylesheet/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="stylesheet/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.png" />
    <script src="script/script.js" />
</h:head>

<h:body>



    <h:form id="secondForm">


        <a4j:commandLink id="pendingTransactions"
            action="#{tellerBean.filterTransactions}"
            value="Show Pending" styleClass="button category-btn">

        </a4j:commandLink>
        <a4j:commandLink id="processedTransactions"
            action="#{tellerBean.filterTransactions}" 
            value="Show Processed" styleClass="button category-btn">

        </a4j:commandLink>
        <a4j:commandLink id="allTransactions" 
            action="#{tellerBean.filterTransactions}" value="Show All"
            styleClass="button category-btn">

        </a4j:commandLink>


    </h:form>



</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which `commandLink`? Please shorten the code so people don't have to search and inspect everything. Also, please post the relevant part of the backing bean.

Comment: I have shortened the question. They are no errors thrown, and the backing bean is just simply a bean with a value.

Comment: They are three. When i click the one the first time, the function in the backing bean is not called. The second time, it is called. No matter which of the three are clicked for the first time the value in the  backing bean is not updated. Only the second time onwards its called.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Isn't this like [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008047/)?

Comment: That is but its another context. My question here are there are three commandLinks. When i press them i want to update my model, and populate a grid. The Grid part is currentdsly under work. The problem is that the first time i press any of three command links, the backing function is not called. The second time and onwards it is called.

Comment: You are using the `render` attribute wrong. The `render` attribute specifies if an element should be rendered, the value of the attribute should be a boolean. I think what you want is `reRender` instead of `render` to update the form.

Comment: I have removed the render attribute completely, but it still does not work.

Comment: The problem is not visible in the code posted so far. Didn't you oversimplify too much without actually having tested it yourself? Have you copypasted and tested exactly the given code? Does it still expose the problem? Please note that we assume that the particular page is just been opened standalone by a regular request, not as an include, nor by ajax, etc.

Comment: Yes this is a standalone page. If i send you this project, would it be possible for you to have a look at it. The first time i click the button, the form is not posted. Only the second time onward does the form begin to post. This is a problem with all the controls on the page. I really cannot see what is going on. There however is a page that redirects to this page ? Could that be a problem.

Comment: OK - Now this is strange. I have a button on page 1 that redirects to page 2. This is when the problem happens. If i go directly to page 2, then this problem does not occur. Is there some context that needs to be fixed or something ?

Comment: @BalusC - Any solution. Its as if the first time, the component in whihc it is, is not initialized. Only after the second time is some component created.

Comment: I can explain this problem if the page is been opened by ajax, not if the page is been opened standalone (directly; synchronously; at its own).

Comment: You shouldn't have the need to send the whole project. It's strongly recommended to provide exactly the code with which *you* can still reproduce the problem on a *blank* JSF project with all settings set to *default* (unless otherwise mentioned in question) by just copy'n'pasting'n'running the entire code *without* making any changes. This way others can do the same and see the problem themselves. See also "SSCCE" part here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info